# Latex plugin for Vim that supports files organized in multiple directories

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex, plugin-vimtex, plugin-latex-box

I have a multiple file/folder project that looks like the following.

```
├── 0_Preamble
│   ├── 01_TitlePage.tex
│   ├── 02_TitleBack.tex
│   ├── 03_Dedication.tex
│   ├── 0_Preamble.tex
├── 1_Theory
│   ├── 11_Problem.tex
│   ├── 12_RelatedWork.tex
│   ├── 1_Theory.tex
│   └── img
├── 2_Experimental
│   ├── 21_CodeStructure.tex
│   ├── 22_Data.tex
│   ├── 2_Experimental.tex
│   └── img
├── 3_Conclusion
│   ├── 31_PrincipalResults.tex
│   ├── 3_Conclusion.tex
│   └── img
├── _master.tex
├── _master.toc
├── _references.bib
```

Each folder has a main file with the same name where all the other files from that folder are included.

For example, `1_Theory.tex` has the following:

```
\chapter{Theory Aspects}
\input{11_Problem.tex}
\input{12_RelatedWork.tex}
\input{13_OurApproach.tex}
```

The master file `_master.tex` (which is the main file that is compilated) includes all the main folder files, this means:

```
\begin{document}
\subimport{0_Preamble/}{0_Preamble.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\subimport{1_Theory/}{1_Theory.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\subimport{2_Experimental/}{2_Experimental.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\subimport{3_Conclusion/}{3_Conclusion.tex}
\end{document}
```

I've been trying to use the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin, which normally support multifiles project, as long as these are all included from the same main file (if I understood correcly from the docs).

**Anybody knows how to use it with a project like mine?** Another more suitable plugin is also an option.

Most of all, I would like the auto-completion function to work (with labels, references, etc.).

Comment: Hi. First, if you have a particular issue with vimtex, please don't hesitate to open an issue on github. So, do I understand correctly that the main file, that is, the one you would initiate compilation with, is the file `0_preamble/0_preamble.tex`?

Comment: Hmm, no, I see you include it in the master file with `subimport`. I've not heard of this command, but it explains why things don't work with vimtex. If you want support in vimtex, you must open an issue and explain what `subimport` is. I'll consider to add the feature.

Comment: Hi, I didn't think at first to have any issues with vimtex. It was more a question about how to use it and set it up for it to work with my project. `subimport` is part of the  `import` package, which allows to have a file structure like the one shown. The main file is `_master.tex`: it's from there where the compilation starts. Thanks for the comments, I will open an issue.